# Load script file dynamically in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, partial-views

I'm using ASP.NET MVC. I have a view that loads contents of a partial view in a section.

Problem is that partial view has some script references in it. so when I load contents of that partial view in the main page, script tags get removed to protect view against script injection attacks.

I have tried different ways to filter script tags out of partial page content and load theme separately but I was unsuccessful.

For example I have tried to filter script tags and append them in the head of main page like this :

```
 var scripts = $(content).filter('script'); 
 $(scripts).each(function() {
 $('head').append($(this));
```

I have also tried to load those scripts using $.getscript. The function gets executed nicely but they don't appear in page resource in chrome developer tools. and I cannot use functions inside those scripts.

how can I achieve this ??

Comment: Have you checked what's the value of `scripts` variable after `filter`? Are there no errors in console?

Comment: "scripts" is an array of script objects and if you put "this.src" in foreach statement it gives you complete script tag. There's no error when injection is take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move all references of script to Main view or you can use $.ajax "dataType as script" to load script dynamically:

http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

```
$.ajax({
  dataType : 'script',
  url : 'http://example.com',
  success : function() {
  console.log(a);
  }
});
```

Comment: In the ajax call, what should the url look like?  Using the filepath from BundleConfig ("~/Scripts/app/UsageReport/AggregatedUsageReport.js") is not working and neither does the path that was in the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/App/UsageReport").  I have no idea how to include a url that points to the location of the javascript file.

Comment: OK.  I figured out the url.  It is where the file exists relative to the location of the view file (url: "../../Scripts/app/UsageReport/AggregatedUsageReport.js")