# ASP.NET MVC Partial view JavaScript move to Main view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm lost with so many examples and solutions out here I cannot seem to find anything that makes sense to me.  So, I'm going to take a baby step and ask [How do you move JavaScript file reference from existing view (that will now be a Partial view) to Main view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16188227/1735836)

### Existing Report View

This will become my partial view, so I cannot use the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/App/UsageReport")` anymore.  Once this is rendered as a partial page I must include this JavaScript file in the Main page.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Usage Report";
}
<main id="usageData">
    .
    .
    .
    <div id="loading">
    </div>
</main>

@section scripts{

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/App/UsageReport")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () { UsageReport.initModule() });
    </script>
}
```

### Main View

Where / How do I include UsageReport.js in the Main view shown below?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main View";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<main id="mainView">
    .
    .
    .
    <div id="loading">
    </div>
</main>

@section scripts{

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/App/MainView")

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () { MainView.initModule('@ViewBag.Name') });
    </script>
}
```

I'll include any other code you need but I'm not sure what is important to add for this dumbass question.

Comment: Just add the `Scripts.Render("~/bundles/App/UsageReport")`  in the `@section scripts{` of your main view. It not clear what `UsageReport.initModule()` does, but if the partial is loaded dynamically, you would need to call that in the success call back of the ajax call

Comment: This is a great start.  Thank you.

Comment: In the ajax call, what should the url look like?  Using the filepath from BundleConfig ("~/Scripts/app/UsageReport/AggregatedUsageReport.js") is not working and neither does the path that was in the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/App/UsageReport")

Comment: OK.  I figured out the url.  It is where the file exists relative to the location of the view file (url: "../../Scripts/app/UsageReport/AggregatedUsageReport.js")

Comment: YAY!!!!  That worked!  :-)

Comment: Your 3 previous comments do not make sense and its not clear what your now trying to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Sorry for the confusion.  I was using your suggestion, "but if the partial is loaded dynamically, you would need to call that in the success call back of the ajax call."  I figured out the correct url to load the JavaScript and it works perfectly.  Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have added some comment in our [previous chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164301/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-patricia)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - You are awesome.  I got everything working very well for a report on one tab.  However opening another tab with the same report partial view, the JavaScript only works for the first tab.  So now we are looking at what a JavaScript class can provide as we need separate instances for each tab.  In case you're wondering, customers want to run the same report with different criteria and switch back and forth between tabs to look at results.

Comment: That would mean the the code in your scripts is wrong :) Suggest you ask a new question explaining what your wanting to achieve, with the relevant code and what is not working.

Comment: New Question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/48697450/1735836

Comment: I'll add comments to the chat :)